# Where are the log files?

Tags: nodered

I installed some nodes for Home Assistant through the Palette Manager, and when I try to put any of them in a flow, I get this error upon "deploy":

Flows stopped due to missing node types. Check logs for details.

Where are the logs I am supposed to check?

Answer (score 1):

Under standard practice, logs are inside /var/log/ but if it's a custom-built app, then they could be anywhere. If you are using systemd to start/stop it, then you might get more information by looking at journalctl (the command).

Comment: I know it's against policy here, but, Thanks.  The installation is as vanilla as possible, but journalctl returns "No journal files were found".  And there's tons of log files in /etc/log, but none regarding node-red, and those that were touched today reveal nothing.  However, I am realizing that I should look to see if there's a node-red section on Stack Exchange.